# A switch expression? Possible in any language?

Tags: switch-statement, expression

So is it possible to use a case statement in C++ and have a expression with it? Should I just use an if statement? My main question is illustrated as the following case statements I am trying to work with:

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double balance;
    int amount;
    const double TWENTY_AMOUNT = .10;
    const  double THIRTY_AMOUNT = .08;
    const double FOURTY_AMOUNT = .06;
    const double SIXTY_AMOUNT = .04;

    cout << "What is your beginning balance?" << endl;
    cin >> balance;

    cout << "How many checks did you write?" << endl;
    cin >> amount;

    if (balance < 400) 
    {
        balance = balance - 15;
        cout << "Your account went below $400, $15 taken off" << endl;
    }


    switch (amount)
    {
        case (<= 20):
        balance = balance + (TWENTY_AMOUNT * amount);
        break;

        case (> 20 && <= 39):
        balance = balance + (THIRTY_AMOUNT * amount);
        break;
        case (> 40 && <= 59):
        balance = balance + (FOURTY_AMOUNT * amount);
        break;
        case ( > 60):
        balance = balance + (SIXTY_AMOUNT * amount);
        break;
        case (< 0):
        cout << "Account overdrawn!";
        default:
        cout << "Incorrect amount!";
    }

    cout << "There is an additional $10 fee this month" << endl;
    balance = balance - 10;

    cout << "You currently have: $" << balance << "This month " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I orginally had the amount variable in the case: expressions. That threw errors too though.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094776/is-it-possible-to-do-the-following-in-a-switch-statement-c

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no: case statements are purely to check value cases of integers and characters (in C++). You should use if statements if you are looking for this sort of conditional flow.